# Boto3 : Invalid IAM Instance Profile ARN when calling client.associate_iam_instance_profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, boto

Steps that brought this error

1. Disassociated a instance profile from an ec2 instance (successful)
2. Associating a new instance profile to the EC2 instance . This fails with an error:

```
Value (arn:aws:iam::1234556:instance-profile/test-instance-profile) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.arn is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile ARN
```

code

```
client.associate_iam_instance_profile(
            IamInstanceProfile={
                'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::1234556:instance-profile/test-instance-profile'
            },
            InstanceId=instance_id
        )
```

I verified the the instance profile exists before associating it

Comment: can you try associating the mentioned profile with the instance via console ? do you have the necessary `trust` policy attached to `profile` so that it can be assumed by `ec2` ? like it is described in this doc [Step 4: Create an IAM instance profile for your Amazon EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html). Just validate that it works.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added the ec2 trust relationship and it still errors out. What I found is if I sleep 5 seconds before associating the instance profile after it's created , it works. Trying to find a better way as I am not a fan of static waits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, `trust policy` in the IAM role was missing for `EC2`

The delay you are seeing for `InstanceProfile` is intended; this is to account for and ensure the IAM service has propagated the profile fully. We do apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.

[AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile resources always take exactly 2 minutes to create](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=593651)

Even though the above post is a bit old, and AWS mimimise the delay, but it still exists.

[Invalid IAM Instance Profile name #15341](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15341#issuecomment-312886409)

> This happened to me as well. There seems to be some race condition for newly created profiles. When I wait a short period and rerun the terraform it succeeds.

Comment: This clarifies the issue . Thank you very much!

Comment: @mwaks if this works for you can you mark this resolved. This helps the community and anyone who else stumbles upon this in the future.

Comment: I tried using a boto3 ```IAM.Waiter.InstanceProfileExists ``` waiter but that didn't make the difference either.

Comment: @mwaks that still is 40 seconds [Polls IAM.Client.get_instance_profile() every 1 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 40 failed checks.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#waiters). And as per the doc I shared , it can take upto 2 minutes.